# Template function defined in header but still get unresolved external symbol error

Tags: c++, templates, linker-errors

I have a simple class that writes to a text file for logging. It's not a template class but I want to give it a template method for adding a new entry. That way I won't have to write separate methods for signed char*, unsigned char*, std::string, ect.

I am getting an Unresolved External Symbol error when building.
I researched my problem and learned that I either have to define the template function in the header file, or use the export keyword in the definition in the source file.
Using the export keyword didn't work so I've defined it in the header file but I'm still getting the error.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 with C++17 as the Language Standard.
Javelin::Log is in a project called 'Javelin' which creates a static library that the project 'Sygdas' has a reference to.

***Log.hpp*** (in Javelin Project)

```
#pragma once
#include "pch.hpp"
#include "Utility.hpp"

namespace Javelin
{
    class Log
    {
    public:
        Log(std::string filename);
        ~Log();

        template<typename T>
        void AddEntry(T entry)
        {
            m_file << GetCurrentTime() << " - " << entry << '\n';
        }

    private:
        std::ofstream m_file;
    };
}
```

***Globals.hpp*** (in Sygdas Project)

```
#pragma once
#include "Javelin.hpp" // includes Log.hpp

namespace Sygdas
{
    inline Javelin::Log game_log{ "log.txt" };
}
```

***Application.cpp*** (in Sygdas Project)

```
#pragma once
#include "wxpch.hpp"
#include "Application.hpp"
#include "Javelin.hpp" // includes Log.hpp
#include "Globals.hpp"

namespace Sygdas
{
    wxIMPLEMENT_APP(Application);

    bool Application::OnInit()
    {
        game_log.AddEntry("Game Launched");
        m_main_frame = new MainFrame();
        return true;
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

> `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class
>   std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class
>   std::allocator<char> > __cdecl Javelin::GetTickCount(void)"
>   (?GetTickCount@Javelin@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
>   referenced in function "public: void __cdecl
>   Javelin::Log::AddEntry<char const *>(char const *)"
>   (??$AddEntry@PEBD@Log@Javelin@@QEAAXPEBD@Z)`

It builds fine if I remove the line `game_log.AddEntry("Game Launched");` from Application.cpp.

I understand why the definition must be in the header file; the compiler needs to know the definition of a template in order to use the template to create a function.
I don't understand why Application.cpp doesn't have the definition when it's in Log.hpp, which gets included via Javelin.hpp.

Any help is appreciated.

**GetCurrentTime() definition**

```
std::string GetCurrentTime()
{
    time_t now{ time(&now) };
    tm calendar{};
    localtime_s(&calendar, &now);
    char time_text[20]{};
    strftime(time_text, sizeof(time_text), "%F %T", &calendar);
    return std::string{ time_text };
}
```

Comment: Does Javelin have a `.lib` file that you need to link with?

Comment: Javelin does create a .lib file. I had written a non-template method to create an entry. I was able to use call that method in Sygdas, and have it build successfully, and the application would write correctly to the text file. In other words, Sygdas does get correctly linked to Javelin.

Comment: Where is the definition (or declaration) of `GetTickCount`?

Comment: I don't know. It's not something I wrote. I'm guessing it's in <chrono> and getting called while GetCurrentTime() is running.

Comment: I'll add GetCurrentTime() definition to post.

Comment: @firehazard The error message says that `GetTickCount()` is in the `Javelin` namespace, which suggests it *is* in your code (unless you messed up and have an `#include` somewhere inside your namespace block). The error message also says that the reference is in `Javelin::Log::AddEntry()`, which does not match the code you've shown. Hmm... maybe you could go for a [mcve] where you try putting all of the necessary code in one file?

Comment: I've had a look in Javelin (it's very small) and I cannot find any #includes in the namespace, nor did I ever write a function called GetTickCount(). I'll do as you suggest and make a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. It was pretty stupid. Application.cpp didn't have a definition for GetCurrentTime(). I inlined that function and now it's building successfully. I feel really stupid for not realising it earlier. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application.cpp didn't have a definition for GetCurrentTime().